# What does the second parameter inherit when the call back function is being used for mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I read the documentation of mongoose and I still don't quite understand the second parameter in the callback function in find function.

```
Item.find({},function(err,items){
    
  });
```

for example I have a DB that is called Items and the model is called Item, so does the items just become an array that contains all the document I have in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`err` will have error details if any error occurred.

`items` will have result documents in case of success request.

That's a callback after `find` executed - you can decide what needs to be in case of err/data.

[Refer](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Sample from doc:

```
// executes, passing results to callback
MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }}, function (err, docs) {});
```

Comment: So does the docs acts like an array that stores all the documents that I wanted to find?